# Removing an element by index in a linked list

Tags: java

A method for removing an element from a linked list has been implemented:

```
public void remove(T e) {
 
    Node<T> node = first;
    Node<T> prevNode = null;
    while(node != null){
        if(e.equals(node)){
            if(prevNode  == null) {
                first = node.next;
            }
            else {
                prevNode.next = node.next;
            }
            size--;
        }
        else {
            prevNode = node;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }
}
```

How to correctly implement deleting an element by index? Using the capabilities of the remove method.

```
public void removeByIndex(int i) {
    remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public void remove(int i) {
    if (i >= size || i < 0) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Node<T> remove;
    if (i == 0) {
        remove = first;
        first = first.next;
        first.prev = null; // <- For double linked list
    } else {
        Node<T> node = first;
        for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j) {
            node = node.next;
        }
        remove = node.next;
        if (i == size - 1) {
            node.next = null;
        } else {
            node.next.next.prev = node; // <- For double linked list
            node.next = node.next.next;
        }
    }
    // Clear links from removed Node
    remove.next = null;
    remove.prev = null; // <- For double linked list
    size--;
}
```

Find the node before position i. Point that node to the "over next" node.

**Edit**
The original code example was a rough sketch at best. Updated with a more complete version.

**Edit #2**

Slight improvements:

- Clears links from the removed node
- Also handles double linked lists

Comment: LinkedList is linked both ways, you also have to link the next node's previous node.  Check my answer.

Comment: From these examples, nothing works - NullPointerException

Comment: @tibetiroka I see nothing in the question that indicates that the list is double linked. The remove(T t) example does not indicate there being a back link.

Comment: Fixed the NullPointerException.

Comment: @DarkMatte `node.next.next.prev` where will it link?

Comment: Updated the code to handle double linked lists and also properly clear links from the removed `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

```
remove(get(i));
```

This is not the most efficient solution, but a simple one which uses the `remove(T)` method. You call it with `get(i)` as the object to be removed - which is the element at the specified index.

Note: This solution has some issues if the list has duplicate values, but in that case you shouldn't use the `remove(T)` method anyway. If you want it to be safe, iterate to the specified index:

```
    Node<T> node = first;       
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
        prevNode=node;
        node=node.next;
    }
```

and do this:

```
node.prev.next=node.next;
node.next.prev=node.prev;
size--;
```

Of course, this is just a rough implementation. To ensure full compability, you should check if the index is valid and use the `unlink(Node)` method of LinkedList.

The LinkedList also has an implementation for the `remove(int)` method:

```
checkElementIndex(index);
return unlink(node(index));
```